# How do you add a notification observer other than 'self'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

It just took me twice as long to learn Notifications as it did to learn CoreData. Is there something not right about that? Anyway, now that I've read all about the isa pointer and all the potential of the (id) type, I'm wondering what I need to do to put something besides 'self' into the NSNotificationCenter addObserver:(id) method?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything special. Make any object the observer. As long as it implements the selector your provide, it works. All you need is a reference to the object and a little knowledge of what methods it implements.

I'm not sure what this has to do with Core Data.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. 

I apologize, it has nothing to do with CoreData. I'm on a bit of a crash course to learn these technologies this week and it struck me as odd that the simple tasks of notifications have taken so long to learn  relative to Core Data. Likely more about the numbers of common customers who have vetted the documentation.

The ignorance on my part (and it seems to be a common beginner's issue) was in not knowing that an instance allocated or initiated returns an (id) pointer that is precisely the same as the isa pointer for the instance, whereas a class will not do.